# Fill color affects shadow in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, uicolor

I have a SwiftUI view that applies a fill and shadow to a shape like this:

```
struct ShadowRectangle: View {
    let color: UIColor
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(Color(color))
            .shadow(color: .red, radius: 5, x: 0, y: 0)
    }
}
```

I have found that the fill color I use for this view can affect the way the shadow is drawn. For example:

```
VStack {
    ShadowRectangle(color: .white)
    ShadowRectangle(color: .quaternaryLabel)
}
```

will look like

[image: two rectangles generated by the code above]

What's going on here? How can I use `UIColor.quaternaryLabel` without messing up the shadow applied to the shape?

Comment: .quaternaryLabel seems to mess up SwiftUI views in all kinds of weird ways.

Answer (score -1):

Try using the `UIColor(red:green:blue:alpha)` initializer (the value is `.quaternaryLabel` converted to RGB):

```
ShadowRectangle(color: UIColor(red: 0.863, green: 0.863, blue: 0.867, alpha: 1))
```